# Join two pandas datagrames by a column (Country Codes)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to have country codes represented in df dataframe as alpha_3_code, in my field Nationality_Codes of df2 dataframe. For every row in df2 I want to match Reviewer_Nationality with en_short_name in df, and if match, assign country code to Nationality_Codes in df2.

`df2.head()`

```
Nationality_Codes   Reviewer_Nationality    Reviewer_Score
NaN                       Russia                  2.9
NaN                       United Kingdom          7.5
NaN                       Australia               7.1
NaN                       United Kingdom          3.8
NaN                       Russia                  6.7
```

`df.head()`

```
alpha_3_code       en_short_name           nationality
RUS                 Russia                  Russian
ALA                 Åland Islands           Åland Island
ALB                 Albania                 Albanian 
AUS                 Australia               Australian
UK                  United Kingdom          British, UK
```

Final Result should be:

`df2.head()`

```
Nationality_Codes   Reviewer_Nationality    Reviewer_Score
RUS                       Russia                  2.9
UK                        United Kingdom          7.5
AUS                       Australia               7.1
UK                        United Kingdom          3.8
RUS                       Russia                  6.7
```

I tried this code, but didn't worked.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
for index2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
    if row2['Reviewer_Nationality']==row['en_short_name']:
        df2['Nationality_Codes'][row2]=df['alpha_3_code'][row2]
```

Can anyone help me?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to create a Series mapping for your english names and codes, and use `.map`:

```
#my_map = pd.Series(df.alpha_3_code.values,index=df.en_short_name)
my_map = df.set_index('en_short_name')['alpha_3_code']

df2['Nationality_Codes'] = df2['Reviewer_Nationality'].map(my_map)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> df2
  Nationality_Codes Reviewer_Nationality  Reviewer_Score
0               RUS               Russia             2.9
1                UK       United Kingdom             7.5
2               AUS            Australia             7.1
3                UK       United Kingdom             3.8
4               RUS               Russia             6.7
```

Comment: Yes, that would be also possible, similar to @twolffpiggott's answer. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need `to_dict`. If `my_map` is a series, you can just use `df2['Reviewer_Nationality'].map(my_map.get)`.

Comment: better is `my_map = df.set_index('en_short_name')['alpha_3_code']`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
merged = df[['alpha_3_code', 'en_short_name']].merge(df2[['Reviewer_Nationality',
                                                    'Reviewer_Score']],
left_on='en_short_name', right_on='Reviewer_Nationality', how='left')]
.rename(columns={'alpha_3_code': 'Nationality_Codes'})\
.drop('en_short_name', axis=1)
```